# Special case for last element with \foreach

Tags: macros, foreach

I want to create a function that generates a list of equation references from a comma delimited input list.  e.g.

```
\erefs{eq:first, eq:second, eq:third}
\erefs{eq:first}
```

yields, the following:

```
(\ref{eq:first}), (\ref{eq:second}), and (\ref{eq:third})
(\ref{eq:first})
```

I am able to take care of the 1 item list correctly , but am having trouble generating the 'and' for the last element.  Any ideas on how to add the 'and' to this code?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz, amsmath, hyperref}

\def\erefs#1{%
 \gdef\firstelement{1}
 \foreach \e [count=\ni] in {#1}{%
   \ifnum\firstelement=0 , \fi %
   (\ref{\e})%
   \gdef\firstelement{0}%
 }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}\label{eq:first}\end{equation}
\begin{equation}\label{eq:second}\end{equation}
\begin{equation}\label{eq:third}\end{equation}
\erefs{eq:first, eq:second, eq:third}
\erefs{eq:first}
\end{document}
```

I need to use hyperref and amsmath packages concurrently

**ADDITION:**
I frequently use `\package{xr}` and `\externaldocument{...}` to refer to a technical appendix, and like to put `TA.` in front of those references.  It would be nice if an optional parameter could be passed for a prefix

I want to create a function that generates a list of equation references from a comma delimited input list.  e.g.

```
\erefs{eq:first, eq:second, eq:third}
\erefs{eq:first}
\erefs[TA]{eq:first, eq:second, eq:third}
\erefs[TA]{eq:first}
```

yields, the following:

```
(\ref{eq:first}), (\ref{eq:second}), and (\ref{eq:third})
(\ref{eq:first})
(TA.\ref{eq:first}), (TA.\ref{eq:second}), and (TA.\ref{eq:third})
(TA.\ref{eq:first})
```

Comment: Have you seen the [`cleveref` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/cleveref)? It does this sort of thing out of the box.

Comment: I haven't, thank you.  Very useful.  Still would love to learn how to do this for other cases though.

Comment: Alas, cleveref is incompatible with using amsmath and hyperref at the same time, which I have.  But looks like a great package.

Comment: possible duplicate of [pgffor: Special treatment for last item in \foreach-list](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16198/pgffor-special-treatment-for-last-item-in-foreach-list)

Comment: Perhaps `forcsvlist` from `etoolbox` package might help?

Comment: @PeterGrill, On whether this is a duplicate: I had based my code off of that item, but couldn't figure out how to do the last item.  Most of the solutions there swap the problem to be the first one as a special case.  In this example I need both.

Comment: @jlperla: OK. It would be helpful if you mentioned that kind of information in the question itself.  BTW, [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436).  Also,  it is always a good deal to post a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages that sets up the problem.  While solving problems can be fun, setting them up is not. Then, those trying to help can simply cut and paste your MWE and get started on solving the problem.

Comment: `cleveref` work fine with `amsmath` and `hyperref`; see [Difference between ref, varioref and cleveref. Decision for a thesis](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/83051), for example :)

Comment: @cmhughes Thanks for the pointer, I figured out the ordering of the packages. The cleveref docs are a little confusing on the compatibility.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here's a way without `cleveref`, but it needs a recent version of `expl3`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse,amsmath}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\erefs}{sm}
 {
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}
    { \jlperla_erefs:Nn \ref { #2 } }
    { \jlperla_erefs:Nn \eqref { #2 } }
 }
\seq_new:N \l_jlperla_input_seq
\seq_new:N \l_jlperla_output_seq
\cs_new_protected:Npn \jlperla_erefs:Nn #1 #2
 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_jlperla_input_seq { , } { #2 }
  \seq_clear:N \l_jlperla_output_seq
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \l_jlperla_input_seq
   {
    \seq_put_right:Nn \l_jlperla_output_seq { #1 { ##1 } }
   }
  \seq_use:Nnnn \l_jlperla_output_seq
   { ~ and ~ }   % between two
   { , ~ }       % between more than two
   { , ~ and ~ } % between last two
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
Some text before
\begin{align}
0+0&=0\label{eq:first}\\
0+1&=1\label{eq:second}\\
1+1&=2\label{eq:third}
\end{align}

One: \erefs{eq:first}

Two: \erefs{eq:second, eq:third}

Three: \erefs{eq:first,eq:second,eq:third}

One: \erefs*{eq:first}

Two: \erefs*{eq:second, eq:third}

Three: \erefs*{eq:first,eq:second,eq:third}

\end{document}
```

The *-version uses `\ref`, while the normal version uses `\eqref` (which is better for equations).

[image]

The “input” sequence is set to the labels, the cycle adds `\ref` or `\eqref` around them. Then `\seq_use:Nnnn` does the right thing in all cases.

---

Here's the modification for allowing a prefix. I hook into `\eqref`, defining a similar command in order the special formatting is applied.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse,amsmath}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\peqref}[2]{\textup{\tagform@{#1\ref{#2}}}}
\newcommand{\pref}[2]{#1\ref{#2}}
\makeatother

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\erefs}{ s o m }
 {
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}
    {
     \IfNoValueTF{#2}
      { \jlperla_erefs:Nnn \pref { } { #3 } }
      { \jlperla_erefs:Nnn \pref { #2. } { #3 } }
    }
    {
     \IfNoValueTF{#2}
      { \jlperla_erefs:Nnn \peqref { } { #3 } }
      { \jlperla_erefs:Nnn \peqref { #2. } { #3 } }
    }
 }
\seq_new:N \l_jlperla_input_seq
\seq_new:N \l_jlperla_output_seq
\cs_new_protected:Npn \jlperla_erefs:Nnn #1 #2 #3
 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_jlperla_input_seq { , } { #3 }
  \seq_clear:N \l_jlperla_output_seq
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \l_jlperla_input_seq
   {
    \seq_put_right:Nn \l_jlperla_output_seq { #1 { #2 } { ##1 } }
   }
  \seq_use:Nnnn \l_jlperla_output_seq
   { ~ and ~ }   % between two
   { , ~ }       % between more than two
   { , ~ and ~ } % between last two
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
Some text before
\begin{align}
0+0&=0\label{eq:first}\\
0+1&=1\label{eq:second}\\
1+1&=2\label{eq:third}
\end{align}

No prefix

One: \erefs{eq:first}

Two: \erefs{eq:second, eq:third}

Three: \erefs{eq:first,eq:second,eq:third}

One: \erefs*{eq:first}

Two: \erefs*{eq:second, eq:third}

Three: \erefs*{eq:first,eq:second,eq:third}

\bigskip

With prefix

One: \erefs[TA]{eq:first}

Two: \erefs[TA]{eq:second, eq:third}

Three: \erefs[TA]{eq:first,eq:second,eq:third}

One: \erefs*[TA]{eq:first}

Two: \erefs*[TA]{eq:second, eq:third}

Three: \erefs*[TA]{eq:first,eq:second,eq:third}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Beautiful.  Thank you.  Sorry to bother you with one last requirement, which I had trouble modifying this to include as I don't entirely understand it.  What if I want to pass in an optional parameter which I use to prepend the reference if it exists (I refer to a technical appendix in my paper frequently, and use a TA. in front of the references).  i.e. `\erefs[TA]{TA:eq:myeq}` to `(TA.\eqref{TA:eq:myeq})`?

Comment: @jlperla I think this is worthy a new question, where you can spell out precisely the requirements.

Comment: specification added.

Comment: @jlperla Added change.

Answer (score 7):

You don't really need any additional package, you can just use the loops already in LaTeX:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\def\erefs#1{%
\count@\z@
\@for\tmp:=#1\do{\advance\count@\@ne}%
\edef\xtmp{\ifcase\count@\or\or\ and\ \else, and\ \fi}%
\@for\tmp:=#1\do{%
\advance\count@\m@ne
\edef\tmp{%
  \noexpand\ref{\expandafter\zap@space\tmp\@gobble{} \@empty}}%
\tmp
\ifnum\count@>\@ne, %
\else
\ifnum\count@=\@ne\xtmp
\fi\fi}}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}\label{eq:first}\end{equation}
\begin{equation}\label{eq:second}\end{equation}
\begin{equation}\label{eq:third}\end{equation}


A \erefs{eq:first, eq:second, eq:third}

B \erefs{eq:first, eq:second}

C \erefs{eq:first}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

Here's a general use method that uses [`etoolbox`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

% set up defaults so we don't get an error
% when we try to redefine these commands
\newcommand*{\elementsep}{}%
\newcommand*{\lastelement}{}%
\newcommand*{\prelastelement}{}%

% define the handler macro:
\newcommand*{\dodisplayelement}[1]{%
  \elementsep
  \lastelement
  \renewcommand{\lastelement}{%
    \renewcommand{\elementsep}{, }%
    \renewcommand{\prelastelement}{ and }%
    #1%
  }}%

% define the new command to process a list of elements:
\newcommand*{\displayelements}[1]{%
  % initialise:
  \renewcommand*{\elementsep}{}%
  \renewcommand*{\lastelement}{}%
  \renewcommand*{\prelastelement}{}%
  % Iterate through list
  \forcsvlist{\dodisplayelement}{#1}%
  % Finish off:
  \prelastelement \lastelement
}

\begin{document}

\displayelements{first,second,third,fourth,fifth}

\end{document}
```

Each item is displayed by `\lastelement` so if the item represented a label you could use:

```
% define the handler macro:
\newcommand*{\dodisplayelement}[1]{%
  \elementsep
  \lastelement
  \renewcommand{\lastelement}{%
    \renewcommand{\elementsep}{, }%
    \renewcommand{\prelastelement}{ and }%
    \ref{#1}%
  }}%
```

Answer (score 5):

Here is an adaptation from [pgffor: Special treatment for last item in \foreach-list](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/59808/4301) to provide special case handling of the last element:

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,amsmath}

\newcounter{TotalNumberOfListMembers}%
\newcommand{\SetTotalNumberOfListMembers}[1]{%
    \setcounter{TotalNumberOfListMembers}{0}%
    \foreach \member in {#1} {%
        \stepcounter{TotalNumberOfListMembers}%
    }%
}%

\newcounter{CurrentListMemberCount}%
\newcommand*{\erefs}[1]{%
    \SetTotalNumberOfListMembers{#1}%
    \setcounter{CurrentListMemberCount}{0}%
    \foreach \n  in {#1}{%
        \stepcounter{CurrentListMemberCount}%
        \ifnum\arabic{CurrentListMemberCount}=1 
            (\ref{\n})%
        \else%
            \ifnum\arabic{CurrentListMemberCount}=\arabic{TotalNumberOfListMembers}
                \ifnum\arabic{CurrentListMemberCount}=2
                   \ and
                \else
                   , and
                \fi
                (\ref{\n})
            \else
                , (\ref{\n})%
            \fi
        \fi
    }%
}%

\begin{document}
Some text before
\begin{align}
    0+0&=0\label{eq:first}\\
    0+1&=1\label{eq:second}\\
    1+1&=2\label{eq:third}
\end{align}

One: \erefs{eq:first}

Two: \erefs{eq:second, eq:third}

Three: \erefs{eq:first,eq:second,eq:third}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

With [`\xintFor`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/159191/4686). The optional parameter may be anything, it does not have to be `TA`.

If an expandable way had been asked for, this could be done with some other utilities from [xinttools](http://ctan.org/pkg/xint).

[image: xintforlast]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, hyperref}
\usepackage{xinttools}

\makeatletter
% with optional parameter.
\def\erefs {\@ifnextchar[\@erefsTA\@erefs }

\def\@erefs #1{%
 \xintFor ##1 in {#1}\do 
   {\xintifForFirst{}{, \xintifForLast{and }{}}(\ref{##1})}%
}

\def\@erefsTA [#1]#2{%
 \xintFor ##1 in {#2}\do 
   {\xintifForFirst{}{, \xintifForLast{and }{}}(#1, \ref{##1})}%
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{equation}E=mc^2\label{eq:first}\end{equation}
\begin{equation}E=h\nu\label{eq:second}\end{equation}
\begin{equation}\zeta(s)=0\label{eq:third}\end{equation}

\erefs{eq:first, eq:second, eq:third}

\erefs{eq:first}

\erefs[TA]{eq:first, eq:second, eq:third}

\erefs[TA]{eq:first}
\end{document}
```